# Symfony 5 without doctrine

Tags: symfony, symfony5

How can I install symfony 5 without Doctrine?

My application will get the data from an external API Rest. I must submit the form data to an API. I don't need Doctrine at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

currently Symfony has 2 skeleton version. `website-skeleton` and `skeleton`. if you dont need doctrine you can install the skeleton version and you will get the minimal version of Symfony
`composer create-project symfony/skeleton my_project_name`
source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html

if you already install the website-skeleton and want to remove the Doctrine run this `composer remove symfony/orm-pack` to remove the Doctrine ORM

Comment: Or using symfony binary `symfony new my_project_name` without `--full`